# What are the best 3D scanning mobile apps?

Tags: media-scanner

What are the best 3D scanning mobile apps?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do true 3D scanning you'll need a phone or tablet with a depth scanning technology. Without it, the sizes and/or positions won't be correct.

[Google Tango](https://get.google.com/tango/) (was Project Tango) delivers 3D sensors in a mobile platform. You can see by this highlight reel [Project Tango - Vision Summit 2016](https://youtu.be/k43xJs3Roqg) what the technology is trying to accomplish: tracking in a room/indoors, geometry reconstruction, and various augmented reality overlays.

There are limitations like using infrared projector as part of the motion/depth sensing means that it works best indoors.

One phone, the Lenovo Phab 2 Pro is available, and another phone by Asus has been announced for a mid-2017 release.